# How can Scala not execute this function?

Tags: scala

To practice a little Scala, I decided to implement a cleaner for my iTunes library. The task is to get rid of library entries with broken links.

This is the main part:

```
def findExistingSongs(lib:Seq[Node]) = {
  val songs = lib \ "dict" \ "dict" \\ "dict" //main->tracks
  songs.filter(song => (song \ "dict" \ "string").exists(value => value.text.startsWith("file://localhost/") && fileExists(value.text)))
}

def fileExists(url:String) = {
  val path = url.replaceAll("file://localhost","").replaceAll("%20"," ")
  println(path)
  val file = new File(path)
  file.exists
}
```

When testing it with a toy library, I can clearly see that the `println(path)` statement is only executed once. If I just change the `&& fileExists` part to `&& !fileExists`, the print statement is executed for every entry in my library.

I read about Scala memoization but the `fileExists` function interfaces with the filesystem, so it shouldn't be optimized away. From a logical POV, there's also no way you can just decided that you don't need to call it again, as the parameter value changes for each call and the result depends on it.
And finally, how can it make sense to Scala to only execute it once but not anymore when it's negated?

Comment: Scala does not automatically memoize anything because as you say it does not know if any given method or function (or any expression) is or is not "pure," referentially transparent and / or side-effect-free. As senia says, it does short-circuit some operations such as `exists` and `forall` or `&&` on `Boolean`.

Comment: it's clear now. I had actually even read that `exists` would only give me the first match but I was assuming that this only pertained to the collection `(song \ "dict" \ "string")` and started looking for an explanation of the actual behaviour in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `collection.exists{predicate}` iterates through collection until it finds first element `e` such that `predicate(e) == true`. When it get such element it already knows that such element **exists** in collection, so there is no need to search for second such element.

```
val predicate = { i: Int => println(s"$i > 0 == ${i > 0}"); i > 0 }

(-1 to 3) exists predicate 
// -1 > 0 == false
// 0 > 0 == false
// 1 > 0 == true
// res0: Boolean = true

(1 to 3) exists predicate
// 1 > 0 == true
// res1: Boolean = true
```

As you can see `exists` stops after first `true` it gets from `predicate`.

`exists` works just like `find`: you'll get the same result with `collection.find(predicate).nonEmpty`.